# Why virtual display doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium

I wrote a python selenium automation script for extracting the data. The script works without the headless browser

My concern here is when i am trying to run same automation script by adding headless browser code to my script, it is throwing error like

**Element Not Clickable at this point.**

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1080))
display.start()
```

The above is the code which i tried.How to make my script to work with headless browser (Virtual Display)

Thanks Guys in Advance.

Comment: How are you running the headless browser? Chrome headless doesn't need display as such

Comment: @TarunLalwani, I am trying to run headless browser for my script with selenium python

Comment: You need to scroll to the element before clicking on it. A virtual display often has much smaller dimensions than a real display, so your element is not in the viewport.

Comment: @SiKing, How should I do when i want to click on the top ?

Comment: Scroll the page to the top.

Comment: @SiKing, can help with the line to scroll to the top.                 driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
The above line am using to scroll to the bottom

Comment: Maybe `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0);")`?

Comment: Thanks guys, display = Display(visible=0, size=(1920, 1920)) i have increased the resolution size. It worked.